# Unwanted patterns in texture from repeated, seamless image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I added an Image Texture to a plane using a seamless image.  In the Texture context of Properties window, I set `Scale` to be `X`:10, `Y:`10.

Unsurprisingly, a pattern forms when you zoom out from plane:

[image]

How can I get rid of this pattern?  (this is supposed to be grass, so it should look very random)

EDIT: For example, is there any way to add distortion to how the image is tiled onto the plane?  So if I were to represent the surface of the plane with a grid, the pattern on it would become distorted, like this

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try something like this:

[image]

With undistorted coordinates:

[image]

With distorted coordinates:

[image]

And with a checkered texture:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One solution i found was to add a copy of the same image, make it about 2.5 times larger, and rotate it my about 30 degrees. then use a mixRGB node to mix the 2, and set the factor to a noise texture, which is running through a brightness contrast node...

[image]

i actually keep this saved in my startup file as a nodegroup xD

Comment: Cool, that definitely helped although there were still some patterns left when you zoom out far enough because it's still only made of two repeating patterns (combined in a noisy way).   I suppose you could also add a third or fourth of the same texture with slightly different rotations and scalings.

Comment: @Garrett indeed... either way with textures you will eventually see pattern-ing. I advise that everyone learn how to create procedural textures. Although i will say that the idea you had (gandalf's answer) really intrigues me ...

Answer (score 2):

You could use your brush as a texture in texture painting mode: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Painting#Texture