# Tiling textures across multiple faces

Tags: texturing, uv, unreal-engine

I'm currently trying to get a tiled material to follow flush along different faces, but they are stretched.

[image: As you can see in this image]
[http://i.imgur.com/C36tqR6.png](https://i.imgur.com/C36tqR6.png)

I would like the squares to continue in the next smaller section of the object, but they are stretched. I've tried many different methods of unwrapping the UV, but I have no idea what else to do or what to search for.

Exporting to .fbx for use in UE4 if that helps.

Comment: How did you unwrap you object? How is you material setup and UV coordinates? How is your UV layout? Try from the top view *U > Unwrap > Project from View* with both faces selected. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15081/how-to-repeat-texture-across-surface-must-work-in-scenekit-ios-os-x/15083#15083

Comment: I selected all the faces and then Unwrapped. I don't have the option to Unwrap > Project from View This is the UV layout http://i.imgur.com/H2rdCcx.png

Comment: That is not possible, the option is always there

Comment: I found it! Didn't see it at the bottom of my list, my bad. Seems to have done the trick almost, but its made the texture much bigger and doesn't tile or fit well anymore. http://i.imgur.com/47AkNqA.png

How do I get the sides of the UV with this method? It has stretched the side textures.

Comment: That is the most basic unwrap method it works by projecting from current view. Just align view to those faces and unwrap as well. Adjust sizes in the *UV/Image Editor* to match your expectations.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I stop the cutting of the texture where it should be tiling from? http://i.imgur.com/OusXi06.png

Comment: Make the face size in the UV editor an exact multiple of the texture size. That will obviously only work if your model is sized to a match a square grid.