# BGE: unwanted patterns in ground texture from repeated, seamless image

Tags: texturing, game-engine, uv

I need to texture a 5km x 5km plane. Repeating the texture produces unwanted pattern, although the texture is seamless.

This issue has been [already](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/unwanted-patterns-in-texture-from-repeated-seamless-image) addressed for Cycles but not for BGE.

Is there any way to solve this in the BGE?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is the nature of a grid to repeat the same pattern in a recognizable way. What you need is something that breaks the pattern.

Adding variations to the size does not really help as our brain can easily handle different scales.

Changing rotation can help more as long as the rotation is good enough. But this usually breaks the "seamless".

You can add variations by using more than one tile type. When you have 5+ with random order the repetition is much less noticeable.

Another option is to combine different tiles. This means you mix different tiles to confuse our brain. The repetition of the different "layers" should have a different scale. This way you can get easily a large field with just a few texture tiles that does not look repetitive (like dirt on the ground).

These are just a few ideas.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. I'm also looking at some BlenderSwap terrain models, but these always include mountains, on the contrary my terrain is pretty flat. It's easier to make things look good when there are mountains all around. Also, do you know of any open project with wide terrains and background that I can look into?