# Repetitive Texturing

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

How can i make this texutre look less repetitive?
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15085/how-can-a-texture-converted-to-be-tileable-seamless/15086#15086 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/unwanted-patterns-in-texture-from-repeated-seamless-image

Comment: You can use the technique in this video : https://youtu.be/CQ9VmCN2EsE?t=472 It involves using an additional node to tweak the coordinates. I didn't see this mentioned in the duplicate question