# Geomtry Nodes: point instance texturing

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

I created a cube with a basic texture on it (first picture). Then, using Geomtry Nodes I created a grid and instanced the cube on the the vertices of the grid, so at the end I have the kind of structure of the second picture.
I would like to know if there is a way to texture each of the instanced cubes using geometry nodes so they doesn't seem patched in the grid, instead of just repeating the texture.
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a seamless texture. If you somehow offset the mesh UVs, seams will appear. What you want is to break the repeating patterns. See this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/unwanted-patterns-in-texture-from-repeated-seamless-image or https://erindale.gumroad.com/l/untiling either way it's best resolved in the shader editor rather in the GN modifier

Answer (score 1):

checkout this shader material:

[image]

Geo nodes setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: But using that set up I can't use my UV map for the texture

Comment: i agree with Gorgious...check this out: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8278/unwanted-patterns-in-texture-from-repeated-seamless-image