# Cycles Subsurface Scattering Intersections

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders, subsurface-scattering

I've noticed that whenever objects with a subsurface scattering material intersect with each other, it creates these dark really obvious outlines across the intersection. I haven't been able to find much information on this phenomena, so I was hoping somebody could explain why it happens, and if there are any workarounds. Here's a photo of the issue. I can't share the texture files, because they're from Quixel Megascans, but I'll include the blend file without them, in case just looking at my settings is helpful.

[image]
[image]

Any help it all is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should randomize texture on material level not object ... [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8284/2214) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gc80VyVCvOc)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this particular case, I was hoping to build out a snow scene using a modular asset workflow, where you build out a large environment using a small amount of duplicated assets. Randomizing on a material level would be fine for the ground, but it doesn't work for the rest of the snow assets in my scene (snow piles, ice walls, igloos, etc.). Sorry, I should've been more clear about the goal I was working towards, but thanks anyways.

Comment: I don't think you have any other chance. SSS  is using calculation indeed surface based on face normals ... Overlapping geometry of course generates  crossing light bounce. You would have to use boolean or remesh modifier to generate manifold, that would too dense - heavy for calculation.